# All text underneath CSS

Tags: css, alignment

I want to align a line of text directly underneath a line of text.

HTML

```
<h4 class="support1">Number 123456</h4>
<h4 class="support2">Number 678910</h4>
```

CSS

```
.support1 { float:right;}
.support2 {float:right;}
```

Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3Dtc4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dtc4/2/ use `clear`

Answer (score 2):

Use `clear:right` in `.support2`:

```
.support1, .support2 { float:right;}
.support2 { clear:right; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Dtc4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is the floating necessary?  You could just keep the  elements as block elements and align the text right:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Dtc4/9/

with text-align:right;

Comment: Another way to do it. Thanks Joel.

Answer (score 1):

As header elements are block level elements, they will push subsequent elements down. You can simply use `text-align: right;` to make sure that both are aligned to the right and the block-level effects will take care of them being beneath each other.

CSS

```
.support1, .support2 { 
  text-align:right;
}
```

​
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/23U6Q/

Is that the desired effect?

Comment: No problem. May I ask if the fact that the text was floated was of any importance? If so, you should go with Xander's method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h4 class="support1">Number 12345</h4><br>
<h4 class="support2">Number 678910</h4>
```

**or**

```
.support1 { float:right;}
.support2 {float:right; clear:right; }
```